# React native repeatedly calling mystery websocket url, connection refused

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, websocket

Using my network inspector on my simulator, I'm seeing react native repeatedly try to connect to ws://localhost:7700. There are no websockets in my codebase and it's unclear what actually is failing here. Image is attached via the link. Does anyone know what websocket React Native is attempting to hit and from where?

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-native": "^0.69.4",
```

The server error is:

```
{
  message: "The operation couldn't be completed. Connection refused"
}
```

[Getting repeated attempts to connect to a websocket at localhost:7700](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WLDA.png)

Comment: There is no question in this question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.